# how to make a proper curl request structure?

Tags: api, curl, request

I have this curl request:

```
curl --location --request \
POST 'https://webservice.com/id/input' \
--header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer Jtgpyg.....' \
--form 'inputs=[
  {
    "inputType": "document-photo",
    "data": {      
      "page": "front",
      "filename": "document-frontside.jpeg"
    }
  },
  {
    "inputType": "document-photo",
    "data": {
      "page": "back",
      "filename": "document-backside.jpeg"
    }
  },
  {
    "inputType": "selfie-photo",
    "data": {
      "type": "selfie-photo",
      "filename": "selfie.jpeg"
    }
  }
]' \
--form 'document=c:\Users\Me\Downloads\document.jpeg'\
--form selfie=c:\Users\Me\Downloads\selfie.jpeg
```

I get this error:

> {   "code": 404,   "message": "Verification not found", } curl: (3)
> URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL

I just wanted to know if the structure of my request is correct, maybe the url for the request is incorrect, but before contacting the provider, I would like to make sure whether
my request structure is correct or not.

Thanks.